# Как растянуть Jcomponent?

Tags: java

Подскажите, как растянуть любой `JComponent` (`Jlist`, `JTable`, `JLabel`) как растягивается `JFrame` по умолчанию (меняется размер).

Answer (score 1):

Способы реализации зависят от используемого `Layout` и желаемого результата.

Например, включение изменяемой ширины и высоты при использовании `GroupLayout` приведёт к тому, что элемент управления будет изменять свои размеры в соответствии с размером родительского контейнера.

Если же Вам нужно повторить поведение `JFrame`, установите у родительского контейнера `CardLayout`. Тогда элемент управления не только будет изменять ширину и высоту вместе с ним, но и полностью займёт всё его пространство.